# Check checkboxes if value is present in a database

Tags: php

I have a form that allows the user to add or remove users from a job by using checkboxes.  At the moment the engineer's names etc are stored in a table called 'users' and they are identified by their user type, engineers.  The checkboxes on the form are created by using a while loop to display a mysql query.  This is done so that new users can be added to the database via a webpage at a later date and their name will automatically be added to the list of available engineers.  To add an engineer to a job their name is simply ticked and the form submitted.

This works well but I would like the user to be able to add or remove users by checking and unchecking boxes on another form but I can't think for the life of me how to do this.

The users assigned to a job are stored in a many-to-many table called calls_engineers which has 3 fields

id_ce (unique id)
call_ce (id of job, a foreign key)
engineer_ce (id of engineer, a foreign key)

The engineer_ce is the users primary key in the 'users' table which is 'id'.

The code I have so far is...

```
<?  $sql = "SELECT * FROM calls_engineers WHERE call_ce = '$diary_id'";
      $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
      $row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result);
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE type = 'engineer' ORDER BY first_name";
      $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
      while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ ?>
          <div style="width:70px; float:left">
              <? 
                  if($row2['engineer_ce'] == $row['id']){
              ?>
              <input type="checkbox" name="engineer[]" checked="checked" value="<? echo $row['id']; ?>" />
              <? echo '   '.$row['first_name']; 
              } else { ?>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="engineer[]" value="<? echo $row['id']; ?>" />
              <? echo '   '.$row['first_name'];
              }?>
          </div>
  <?
      }

  ?>
```

All this does is create checkboxes for each user which is an engineer but it doesn't check them if the user is assigned to the job.

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never loops the calls_engineers table. Using

```
$row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

Will not actually find all assignments for the engineer. Now check every single engineer if this is included in current job:

```
<?  

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE type = 'engineer' ORDER BY first_name";
  $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ ?>

      <div style="width:70px; float:left">
          <input type="checkbox" name="engineer[]" <? 
              $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM calls_engineers WHERE call_ce = '".mysql_real_escape_string($diary_id)."' AND engineer_ce = ".$row['id']);
              if(mysql_num_rows($result2) > 0) echo 'checked="checked"';
             ?> value="<? echo $row['id']; ?>" />
          <? echo '   '.$row['first_name']; ?>
      </div>

  <? } ?>
```

Comment: That was the bit I wasn't sure how/where to do.  Could you show me please?

Comment: @tatty27 Now edited - I added a JOIN syntax so just using one query should do it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for that but unfortunately it doesn't work.  There are 3 engineers assigned to the job I am testing this on and it only shows one of them and it doesn't show empty checkboxes for the engineers that aren't assigned to it

Comment: unknown column u.Key in where clause

Comment: I've changed that to u.id and I get the same result as before, only one user is showing

Comment: @tatty27 Sorry maybe someone else can tell us how not to make the second WHERE clause exclude all unchecked users...

Comment: Checked = checked.... You don't need to have both bits. Just checked on its own will do

Comment: @tatty27 Well now a less elegant solution but this should really work anyway!

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking the time to get back to me.  Unfortunately it doesn't fully work but it's a lot closer.  Firstly I was getting a an error which I resolved by replacing (mysql_num_rows($result2) > 0) with ((mysql_num_rows($result2)) > 0) and then replacing engineer_ce = ".$row['id']) with engineer_ce = '$eng_id'" (I stored the $row['id'] in a var).  Now I get checkboxes for all of the engineers but only the ones with the checks in have names next to them, the empty boxes have now names

Comment: I've sussed it!  I added else {echo "value=".$row['id']."\" />";     echo '   '.$row['first_name'];} to the end and now they all show and the correct boxes are ticked.  Thank you so much for your help!!